# How to use Openshift OAuth server as authentication provider for my web app running in openshift cluster?

Tags: openshift, openshift-origin, openshift-enterprise

I am deploying a web application in Openshift cluster. I want to use Openshift authentication to login to the web application. But couldn't find documentation on how to use Openshift authentication for third party apps deployed in Openshift. Can anyone give some pointers here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are two sites / repositories describing how to use the `oauth-proxy` as a sidecar container:

- https://linuxera.org/oauth-proxy-secure-applications-openshift/
- https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/#using-this-proxy-with-openshift

The gist of it is that you'll need to add the `openshift/oauth-proxy` container to your Deployment as a sidecar and route your traffic through this additional container:

```
 apiVersion: apps/v1
 kind: Deployment
[..]
 spec:
[..]
   template:
     spec:
       containers:
         - <YOUR_APPLICATION_CONTAINER>
         - name: oauth-proxy 
           args:
             - -provider=openshift
             - -https-address=:8888
             - -http-address=
             - -email-domain=*
             - -upstream=http://localhost:8080
             - -tls-cert=/etc/tls/private/tls.crt
             - -tls-key=/etc/tls/private/tls.key
             - -client-secret-file=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/token
             - -cookie-secret-file=/etc/proxy/secrets/session_secret
             - -openshift-service-account=reversewords
             - -openshift-ca=/var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount/ca.crt
             - -skip-auth-regex=^/metrics
           image: quay.io/openshift/oauth-proxy:4.6
           ports:
             - name: oauth-proxy
               containerPort: 8888    
               protocol: TCP
```

You can find full examples in the linked repository or the linked tutorial.

Comment: thank you for the tutorial. Do you know how to increase timeout for the requests? Does oauth-proxy uses nginx internally?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "timeout for the requests". There is a config file example available in the repository: https://github.com/openshift/oauth-proxy/blob/master/contrib/oauth-proxy.cfg.example As far as I know it does not use NGINX internally, but can be easily connected to one (see repository)

Answer (score 1):

The doc to configure the internal OAuth server is here:
https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/authentication/configuring-internal-oauth.html

How to configure clients is here: https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/authentication/configuring-oauth-clients.html

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's supported on Openshift (it is for Kubernetes)

```
$ ibmcloud ks cluster addon enable alb-oauth-proxy --cluster xxxxx                                                                           
Enabling add-on alb-oauth-proxy for cluster xxxx...
The add-on might take several minutes to deploy and become ready for use.
FAILED
'alb-oauth-proxy' configuration is not supported on OpenShift clusters. (Ee2a0)

Incident ID: ed45dc90-8516-xxxx
```